# Contenteditable and ng-blur

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable

I have a contenteditble div, that I want to reset on blur if it's empty (i.e. if you delete everything and then click outside, it will discard the changes).

If you delete everything but retain focus, then I want it to show a placeholder.

The code below is almost working, but when I delete the last character in the contenteditble div, it's firing the ng-blur event, even though the div still has focus.

```
<div ng-model="question.QuestionTitle" contenteditable placeholder="Add Question Title" 
ng-blur="saveQuestionnaireTitle(question)"></div>
```

So, when you delete the last character in the div, the placeholder shows for a split second, and then my code inside "saveQuestionnaireTitle" fires, which checks for an empty string repopulates the box - so even though the user hasn't clicked out of the box.

The div appears to loose then quickly regain focus.

Any ideas?